Messenger API to send file from local machine
I'm currently using this document from Meta API to send the file to Messenger via API call
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api/
When I'm trying with using the image URL like the document:

I am successfully got the attachment_id like this:

However when I'm using request for an upload from a file that using file path:

I'm trying to doing the same call on Postman using a path from my local machine that lead to an image, but I got error:

Not sure what I go wrong? Could anyone help?

Not really sure how this is supposed to work. The -d option should cause cURL to  send the request with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded - but apparently they expect it to be overwritten with application/json. Can't see how that is supposed to make much sense.
